# Transform a local variable into a global variable

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, global-variables

i want to create a loop to test if the name that people enter are text file. 
I do my test but if I ask people to re-enter the name of the file, it's not changing the global filename.

I know, it's a question of global and local variable but I cannot find a way to change it.

here is my code :

```
def name():
    global f1
    global t
    global f2
    print('File Name')
    f1 = input()
    t = match(r'.+(\..+$)',f1)
    while t.group(1) != '.txt' :
            print(t.group(1))
            print("New file Name")
            f2 = input()
            f1 = f2
            print(f1)

name()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not even know why you need global variables for this at all, why wouldn't you just rewrite the code into something like as follows:

```
from os.path import splitext

def get_name():
    while True:
        name = input("File name> ")
        if splitext(name)[1] != '.txt':
            print("Invalid name, give another")
        else:
            return name

filename = get_name()
```

Comment: Thanks Antti, I complicated my life with those global and local variable
I went too far to look for answer.